# Is there support for functional layers api support in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm working on converting our model from tensorflow 1.8.0 to 2.0 but using sequential api's is quite difficult for our current model.So if there any support for functional api's in 2.0 as it is not easy to use sequential api's.

Comment: Use tf.keras.Model.

Comment: Thank you.And i want to give two different inputs to two different layers in the model.Is that possible?

Comment: Yes that is possible. tf.keras.Model contains all your layers and takes as many inputs as you like. You can then selectively pass these inputs into the layers inside the call method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow 2.0 is more or less made around the keras apis. You can use the tf.keras.Model for creating both sequential as well as functional apis.